# VBA - Using Columns() in Formula

Tags: vba, excel

Right now i am using this code for a SumIf Formula:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    i = 4
    calc = "=SUM(SUMIF($A$2:$A$22,N3,$B$2:$B$22),"
    Do Until i = lastrow + 1
        calc = calc & "SUMIF($A$2:$A$22,N" & i & ",$B$2:$B$22),"
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    ActiveSheet.Range("N" & lastrow + 1 & ":BI" & lastrow + 1).Value = calc & ")"
End Sub
```

My Question now is, is there a way that i can change the criteria part in calc = calc & SUMIF($A$2:$A$22,**N"** & i & ",$B$2:$B$22)," that it jumps from column N to column M till column BI?

In fact my code works fine, but if i move some cells in the table it also moves the formula. And if i add the $ sign it only uses column N.

I tried to add this, but it doesn´t work

```
i = 4
lCol = 14
calc = "=SUM(SUMIF($A$2:$A$22,N3,$B$2:$B$22),"
Do Until i = lastrow + 1
    calc = calc & "SUMIF($A$2:$A$22," & Columns(i, lCol) & ",$B$2:$B$22),"
    i = i + 1
    lCol = lCol + 1
Loop
```

I hope it is clear what i mean and someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a cell and using its address.

```
calc = calc & "SUMIF($A$2:$A$22," & Cells(i, lCol).address(0, 0) & ",$B$2:$B$22),"
```

Comment: It works, but now i still have the problem that when i add the $ sign after $A$22,$", & .. it still only takes column N and i can not move single cells without moving the formula

Comment: The [syntax for .address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel) is `.address(true/false, true/false).If you want an absolute row then .Address(true, false). If you want an absolute column then .address(0, true). If you want absolute row and column then address(true, true). The one I used above is address(false, false) or relative row, relative column.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeeped:

I tried to change the syntax for .address, but i still does not solve my problem. I hope with the following pictures i can explain it better.

In the first picture you can see how my table looks and which cells are used in the formula.

[image]

In the second picture i moved some cells to the left and unfortunately the formula also moves. This is what i want to prevent

[image]

And if i use .Address(0, 1) the formula looks like this in every column:

=SUM(SUMIF($A$2:$A$22;$N3;$B$2:$B$22),SUMIF($A$2:$A$22;$N4;$B$2:$B$22) ... )